# Select a row programmatically using tabulator selectRow method

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I am using tabulator to create tables on my website. I can select rows by clicking on them and I can select all rows using the tabulator.selectRow() method.

[According to the documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/3.4#selectable):

> To select a specific row you can pass the any of the standard row
>   component look up options into the first argument of the function.

I have seen this a few times but there is no working example. Does anybody know how the row component look up options need to be provided?

Let's say I have rows which have a name field.

I want to select the row where name == 'dennis'.

The documentation suggests that I can pass a lookup option in the selectRow() argument. There is just no example or any indication to expected syntax for the argument.

I currently have this working like so which does not seem to be most intuitive way.

```
table.getRows().forEach(row => {
  if (row.getData().name == 'dennis') row.toggleSelect();
});
```

Or like so:

```
params.layer.tableView.table.getRows()
    .filter(row => row.getData().name == 'dennis')
    .forEach(row => row.toggleSelect());
```

Comment: @oli-folkerd This really ought to be in the documentation and example code where you can add / delete rows. This relatively common task took me a long time to track down and was quite frustrating to me.

Comment: If you just added a button to the add / delete example code where you can delete all rows where the name is 'john' or something like that, it would be enormously helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got there in the end with help via github. [#1749](https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/1749)

The bit which cleared this up for me was this:

> Any function that takes a component as an argument will also attempt
>   to find that component based on the value provided if it is not a
>   component itself.

Here as an example to select my row.

```
table.selectRow(table.getRows().filter(row => row.getData().name == 'Dennis'));
```